# Cloudflare redirect subdomain to directory

Tags: php, nginx, cloudflare

I am trying to use Cloudflare to redirect:

```
http://sub.example.com -> http://example.com/sub
```

But I rather this:

```
http://sub.example.com -> http://example.com/subdomain
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible with Cloudflare Page Rules. In Website Page click on the gear of your site then select **Page Rules**. Then you can add every pattern you want. Like this for example:

[image]

For more information about Cloudflare's Page Rules, take a look at the official site: http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-url-forwarding/